# Assistive technology for people with disability is gaining important since the first report on world disability published in 2011

Tags: word-choice

In the above sentence, the verb "is gaining" and adjective "important", Is it correct?
OR
should I write as
is gaining in important or importance
Which is correct?

Comment: Important is an adjective, importance is a noun. Something can only _gain in_ something which can be named so the correct word is **importance**.

Comment: So, Assistive technology for people with disability is gaining in importance since the first report on world disability published in 201.  This one is correct

Comment: Quibble  - While the WHO report does make extensive use of *disability* as a collective noun, the plural *disabilities* still has a place in the language. *People with disabilities* is idiomatic. Even the foreword to the WHO report by Hawking uses it. And *since* wants a perfect or past tense verb in front of it. The use of *is gaining* should be *has been gaining* or more typically, *has gained*. This is just a quirk of the word *since*.

Comment: @suraj Yes, "gaining in important" is meaningless.